# Error 424 Object needed

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

well my idea is to refer the alphabet in cell J9 of the first worksheet called Table1 and to automatically color the shape called "Test" on the  active worksheet. So basically if the alphabet entered is "a" in the cell J9 on the first worksheet, the shape "Test" on worksheet 2 should give out color 1, and if "b", color 2 and so on. I have written a code for it but sadly I keep receiving Error 424 Object Required. Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks!

```
Sub test()
If Table1.Range("J9") = "a" Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1

ElseIf Table1.Range("J9") = "b" Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 2

ElseIf Table1.Range("J9") = "c" Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 3

ElseIf Table1.Range("J9") = "d" Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 4

Else
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like is not with the shape code but with the `Table1`. Tables use a special structured addressing system (see [Select, get and set data in Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872504/excel-vba-select-get-and-set-data-in-table)). If you just want the value from cell J9 then this should do.

```
With Sheets("Table 1")
    Select Case LCase(.Range("J9").Value)
        Case "a"
            .Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1
        Case "b"
            .Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 2
        Case "c"
            .Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 3
        Case Else
            ' do nothing
    End Select
End With
```

If a simple reference to J9 is insufficient, you will have to provide more information on the exact nature of **Table1**.

**EDIT:**

You may not be referencing the shape's name correctly. This code will enumerate all of hte shapes on the Table 1 worksheet and return their names to the VBE's Immediate window (in the VBE as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).

```
Dim i As Long
With Sheets("Table 1")
    For i = 1 To .Shapes.Count
        Debug.Print .Shapes(i).Name
    Next i
End With
```

Is **Test** there as one of the names? can you determine the name of the shape you want to change?

Comment: Well the data inserted is in a table but the table is not called Table 1. Table 1 is just the name of the sheet. It can be anything. So can it really be the problem?

Comment: @Vin - If you type an *a, b* or *c* into J9 (disregarding the *Table1* reference altogether) then the code above works.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing all Table1 references to Worksheets("Table1") fix it? For example:

```
If Worksheets("Table1").Range("J9") = "a" Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Now the error 424 is gone but there is another error. It says, "error 438: object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

@Jeeped Is it the same if I were to use apple, orange and lemon instead of alphabets? I changed my code to make it similar like yours. This time there is no error message but nothing happens

```
Sub test()
With ActiveSheet
    Select Case LCase(.Range("J9").Value)
        Case "apple"
            .Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1
        Case "orange"
            .Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 2
        Case "lemon"
            .Shapes("Test").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 3
        Case Else
            ' do nothing
    End Select
End With

End Sub
```

Is there anything wrong in this code? and by the way, what is LCase??

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SO()

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Test").Fill.FillColor.SchemeColor = Asc(UCase(Sheets("Table 1").Range("J9"))) - 64

End Sub
```