# Create and Read table in Excel vbUsing VB

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2010

I have Created Excel Workbook 2010 Project in Visual Studio 2010.

[image]

I have Added a ribbon  and Added a Button on it.

I want to Read the Value from the Excel file when I click on the Button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

Also is it possible that on the Load of Excel Sheet, to create a Table?

If yes I want to read that table after Clicking on Button.

Achieved to create table in Excel, please advice , if it is good practice or not.

```
Private Sub Feuil1_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

        With Me
            .ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, .Range("$C$2:$T$7"), , Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes).Name = "Table1"
            .Range("C2").Value = "ZRouteName"
            .Range("D2").Value = "MondayIndicator"
```

On Load of Excelsheet Table is Created

```
Private Sub Feuil1_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    ' Dim nr As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange = _
    'Me.Controls.AddNamedRange(Me.Range("A2"), "NamedRange1")
    'nr.Value2 = "This text was added by using code"
    With Me
        .ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, .Range("$C$2:$T$7"), , Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes).Name = "Table1"
        .Range("C2").Value = "ZRouteName"
        .Range("D2").Value = "MondayIndicator"
        .Range("E2").Value = "TuesdayIndicator"
        .Range("F2").Value = "WednesdayIndicator"
        .Range("G2").Value = "ThursdayIndicator"
        .Range("H2").Value = "FridayIndicator"
        .Range("I2").Value = "SaturdayIndicator"
        .Range("J2").Value = "SundayIndicator"
        .Range("K2").Value = "StartDate"
        .Range("L2").Value = "Zorganiser"
        .Range("M2").Value = "DayNumber"
        .Range("N2").Value = "ZEmployeeResponsible"
        .Range("O2").Value = "VisitDate"
        .Range("P2").Value = "StartTime"
        .Range("Q2").Value = "DriveTime"
        .Range("R2").Value = "PreparationTime"
        .Range("S2").Value = "Duration"
        .Range("T2").Value = "ZAccountID"
    End With
End Sub
```

Now I want to read the values form the Table 1 OnClick Event of Button

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using vbscript and VB6? I think you should remove those tags. Excel-VBA can stay because the code works about the same as VB.Net for Excel automation.

Comment: When you say table, are you actually referring to a table in Excel or simply columns and rows? Bother are possible with what you are doing.

Comment: Would it make more sense for you to create a .Net Excel Addin instead of a Workbook project?

Comment: The Place where I am Writing my code has Extension .vb. I achieved to create a Table in Excel.(Update the Code). Now I want to Read the of the Table when user Click Button in the Ribbon.

Comment: I don't know your variable names, but you should be able to do something like this - `Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook` - `Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = wb.Sheets(1) 'or call it by name` - `Dim val As String = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value`

Comment: @MichaelZ. : What is xlAPP ?

Comment: `Me` in your example looks like a worksheet. `xlApp` would be the Excel.Application, but it is almost certain that you would refer to it by another name.

Comment: Take a look at this link. I think it will answer a lot of question for you, but it will also create many new questions. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168292(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @MichaelZ. : Yes it Created more Question . I dont Understand How to Access `Table 1 `

Comment: I figured it would create more questions. Take a look at this stack overflow answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872504/excel-vba-select-get-and-set-data-in-table

Comment: But, basically, you access the table cells as you would access any other cell in Excel. Does my recent updated answer give an exception? If so, what is the exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112946/discussion-between-gamebuilder-and-michael-z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of accessing your sheet from the ribbon class.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MessageBox.Show(Globals.Feui11.Cells(1, 1).Value)
End Sub
```

Or this using `Range`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show(Globals.Feui11.Range("A1").Value)
End Sub
```

This outer loop iterates through the rows in `UsedRange` and for each row we iterate through the columns. You may not need the column loop if you know which columns you need to look in for your data.

```
For row As Integer = 1 To Globals.Feui11.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 1
            For column As Integer = 1 To Globals.Feui11.UsedRange.Columns.Count Step 1
                'Do stuff with this
                'Globals.Feui11.Cells(row, colunm).Value
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: I am writing my code in `Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click` . It doesnt have Me.Cells.

Comment: If that updated code doesn't work then try taking out the `ActiveWorkbook` part. Can you post the startup code for this project in your original post?

Comment: I'm going to create a test project to help you further. Give me a minute.

Comment: I added what i did till now.. Please check. Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot for your help